# Why increment operator in Conditional statement gives compile error with class Object?

Tags: javascript, java

Increment operator in Conditional Statement is giving compile error while using with class Object.

Below statement gives no error:

```
a = a==0 ? 1 : ++a;
```

But, this statement gives compile error:

```
obj.setValue(obj.getValue()==0 ? 1 : ++obj.getValue());
```

Comment: You're going to want to pick either Java or JavaScript. Having both tags is confusing and tends to trigger people.

Comment: `++obj.getValue()` is the culprit, you cannot use the `++` operator on a method.

Comment: what is the result of `obj.getValue()` in case of `obj.getValue()==0`?

Comment: @Nina Scholz No result as the code gives compile error before it could execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj.getValue()` is a value returned by a method. It's not a variable. Therefore you can't apply any operator that changes the value of the operand (such as --, ++, +=, =, etc...).

You can use:

```
obj.setValue(obj.getValue()==0 ? 1 : obj.getValue() + 1);
```

instead.

Or you can assign the method's return value to a variable, which can be decremented:

```
int a = obj.getValue();
obj.setValue(a==0 ? 1 : ++a);
```

However, there's no reason to use pre-decrement (or post-decrement) operator unless you are going to use the decremented variable later.

Answer (score 2):

The `++` and `--` operators can only be used with an expression that can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment (`=`).  You cannot put a function call on the left-hand side of an assignment, so you can not apply `++` to a function call.

A formal term for the sort of expression I'm talking about is *l-value*. This works:

```
var x = 0;
x++;
```

because `x` as an expression  is an *l-value*.  This also works:

```
var x = { a: 0 };
x.a++;
```

because `x.a` is also a valid *l-value*.

Now it should also be pointed out that technically there *is* a way to use a function call as an *l-value*:

```
var obj = {
  get value() { return this._value; },
  set value(newValue) {
    this._value = newValue;
  },
  _value: 0
};

var x = ++obj.value;
```

Because `value` is defined with a getter/setter pair, the subexpression `++obj.value` will be evaluated by calling the getter function `obj.value`, incrementing the return value, and then calling the setter function. This does not really "disprove" the general rule, of course, because the whole point of using getter/setter functions is to allow simple property access syntax while involving code that adds special semantics.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ++ to increment a "value" returned by a method.

use

```
obj.getValue() + 1
```

instead of

```
++obj.getValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have mentioned, its because the `++` and `--` operators can't be applied to a function.

But taking another look at your code, why are you checking that `obj.getValue()==0`?

if the value is 0, then just increment it just like any other number.

`obj.setValue(obj.getValue() + 1);`

Comment: I think this is the best solution to OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because obj.getValue() is a method/function.

you cannot auto-increment the return value of a function (you must assign it to a variable first and the auto increment would apply to that variable)

Answer (score 0):

Why the condition? You could take a default value and then add one.

```
obj.setValue((obj.getValue() || 0) + 1);
```

Comment: I don't think this compiles because logical OR isn't applicable to `int` in Java.

Comment: it's javascript tagged ... as well. well, in js, it should work if `obj.getValue()` returns either a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value or a number, but who knows ...

Comment: I think the JS tag is just incorrect. OP mentioning "compile error" suggests this is Java instead.